# php redirect not working on wordpress but works on static pages...?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

when I include this code on a static web page, it works fine, however when placed into the header of a wordpress blog it just shows a blank page?

is anyone able to identify any issues with the code below that would cause it to show these errors?

```
<?php
/**
 * Redirect script.
 * ----------------
 * 
 * How it works:
 * 
 * 1. You MUST include this before ANYTHING on your page. E.g:
 * <?php
 *      include 'redirect.php';
 * ?>
 * <html>
 * ...
 * 
 * 2. This script will redirect to an advertise url depending on which id specified. E.g:
 * http://yoursite.com?id=192
 * ... will find ad with id "192" and then redirect to this page.
 * 
 * It will only redirect if ?id= is specified as parameter, otherwise everything works like usual.
 */ 
if(isset($_POST['jviahfwagjfbvjahuiaf']))
{
    echo '<html><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"></head><body><form action="http://'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']).'" method="post" id="formy">
<input type="hidden"  name="rfjafwofa" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['jviahfwagjfbvjahuiaf']).'" /></form>
<script language="JavaScript"> 
document.getElementById(\'formy\').submit();</script></body></html>';
exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['rfjafwofa']))
{
    $ad_id = $_POST['rfjafwofa'];
    // Filter hackers away:
    if(is_numeric($ad_id))
    {
        define('API_URL','http://mysite.com/api.php');
        // First retrive advertisement:
        $response = '';

        // Use cUrl if it exists...
        if(function_exists('curl_init'))
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, API_URL.'?ads_id='.$ad_id);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
         $response = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
        }
        else
        // Otherwise just use this...
        {
            $response = @file_get_contents(API_URL);
        }

        // If advertisement was found:
        if($response != '')
        {
            // Redirect:
            header('Location: '.$response);exit;
        }        
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
echo '<html><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"></head><body><form action="http://'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']).'" method="post" id="formy">
<input type="hidden"  name="jviahfwagjfbvjahuiaf" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']).'" /></form>
<script language="JavaScript"> 
document.getElementById(\'formy\').submit();</script></body></html>';
exit;
}
?>
```

thanks

Comment: Do you have an form element on your page with the id `formy`?
Also, variable names like `jviahfwagjfbvjahuiaf` might be hard for others to follow.  Do these names have any significance?

Comment: What do you mean by "placed into the header of a wordpress blog". Does that mean you placed the sample above between `<head></head>` tags?

Comment: hi, no those don't have any significance, just changed them around for anonymity. 

the code was placed at the top of the header.php template of the wordpress blog. thanks

Comment: @user1332723 WHAT code was placed at the top of the file? A portion of the code above? All of the code above? What are we looking at in the sample??

Comment: hi, all of the code above was placed at the very top of the header.php template in the wordpress install. thanks

Answer (score 2):

the redirect doesnt work because you have outputed something before the header("Location,..") call. If you have added your code to your header you are probably outputing something before your script.

Comment: hi, there is nothing outputted before the header location part??

Comment: hi, that wouldnt make a difference would it? this code works 100% fine on a static web page, but when trying to put into wordpress it fails.

Comment: wordpress is probably outputing something before your code gets executed

Comment: have you any idea how to get this to be the first thing to be executed?

Comment: i dont know how wordpress works but you can you put   ob_start(); before your code and ob_clean() before your header(..) call.

Answer (score 1):

if your header is already sent, you can't send them again.
you could try with.

```
ob_start();
header('Location: '.$response);exit;
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: the header isn't already sent because this code is placed right at the beginning of the header.php template file in wordpress. the code works 100% ok in a non wordpress situation, so i think it must just be a clash with wordpress somehow - but I am not sure how

Answer (score 1):

Based off of the comments above, it sounds like you are placing your code sample within the `<head></head>` tags within `header.php`. If so, remove the `<head></head>` tags from your code above and try again.

Answer (score 0):

the standard php code using header and location just wont work inside a word press install

```
header("Refresh: 1; URL=".$redirect);
```

you have to use either the word press function or this is another solution that worked for me

```
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"10;url=$redirect\" />";
```

I  hope this helps